# Vim - how to fold indented lines into parent line, not underneath it

Tags: vim-folding

With `foldmethod=indent` I can take this text:

```
1. Heading
2.    item one
3.    item two
4.    itme three
```

and fold lines 2, 3 and 4 to achieve this:

```
1. Heading
2. ------------------------------------------
```

where the dotted line is the collapsed lines.

How can I achieve this instead

```
1. Heading ----------------------------------
```

i.e. lines 2, 3 and 4 have collapsed *into* line 1.